# Write real time data to file

Tags: java, file, io, bufferedwriter

How to write real time data to file in Java?

I'm trying to get real time twitter feed to text file. Here is a code that I have written:

```
public void onStatus(Status status) 
{
   User user = status.getUser();
   BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = null;
   try
   {
      bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("c:\\twitterDumponFile.txt"));
      String username = status.getUser().getScreenName();
      bufferedWriter.write(username);

      String profileLocation = user.getLocation();
      bufferedWriter.write(profileLocation);

      String content = status.getText();
      bufferedWriter.write(content);
      bufferedWriter.newLine();

   }
   catch (FileNotFoundException ex) 
   {
      ex.printStackTrace();
   } 
   catch (IOException ex) 
   {
      ex.printStackTrace();
   } 
   finally
   {
      //Closing the BufferedWriter
      try
      {
         if (bufferedWriter != null) 
         {
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
         }
      } 
      catch (IOException ex) 
      {
         ex.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

When I open the file twitterDumponFile.txt it contains a single line of data. Everytime I open it it has a different data but a single line, it is not appending the new data on to the file.

Please help me where I'm getting wrong.

Comment: Have you tried this `bufferedWriter = new FileWriter("c:\\twitterDumponFile.txt", true)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to open the `FileWriter` in  **append** mode.

replace

```
bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("c:\\twitterDumponFile.txt"));
```

by

```
bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("c:\\twitterDumponFile.txt", true));
```

Comment: @Zelig Sorry for digging up, but let's take a case where the real-time data is so heavy, that it could potentially crash the app some times. In that case, will BufferedWriter have written EVERY data that was there prior to the crash? Or, is some flushing mechanism required?

Comment: @Sriram: Depends until you close the BufferedWriter you cannot be sure how much data is still in the buffer and not yet written to the file. In Addition your OS might also buffer writing to the file so you could loose there data too if your application crashes without closing the BufferedWriter.

Comment: @MrSmith42 Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
FileWriter("c:\\twitterDumponFile.txt")
```

This won't append the data to the file, it will write from the beginning of the file, use this instead :

```
FileWriter("c:\\twitterDumponFile.txt", true)
```

This will write to the end of the file rather than the beginning.

See the documentation of [FileWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29).

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the data already on the file instead of appending it.

Use [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html) link to know how to append instead of overwriting...
It's always good way to use the api to know how and abouts of the methods and classes.